# How to quickly get all the processes currently being executed by a multicore processor?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm working on a kernel module that implements a driver.

When my read() file op is called, I can used **current** to get the current running process. But, when read() is entered, I also intend to get all the processes that are currently being executed by other cores on a multicore platform.

I can use **for_each_process()** to iterate each struct task_struct to see if it is **TASK_RUNNING**. But I know this cannot solve my problem, since **TASK_RUNNING** cannot give info about whether the process is being executed by CPU (it just means the corresponding process is runnable). Besides, I don't want to iterate all processes to save some overhead.

Any idea on how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like the makings of hair-tearing debugging attempts when doing something based on this info inevitably leads to a race condition.  I'm pretty sure there isn't any atomically synchronized scheduler info by default.

Comment: (in the interests of being somewhat useful, I'll point you towards `/proc/sched_debug` *try `grep pid`*, but... make sure you've thought this through aye?)

Answer (score 1):

There is command `echo l > /proc/sysrq-trigger`, that shows active tasks on CPU ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key ). You can send `l` from your `read()` function

Or you can try to write your own dump function. That's how it works in current linux kernel:

`sysrq_handle_showallcpus` ( https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.8/source/drivers/tty/sysrq.c#L234 ) =>

`trigger_all_cpu_backtrace` ( https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.8/source/include/linux/nmi.h#L144 ) =>

`arch_trigger_cpumask_backtrace` ( arch dependent )